# traefik loadbalancer server port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

i have a few services in my docker-compose file using traefik labels.

now i would like to clean this file and start using traefik yaml files.

the problem is that i could not find the equivalent to `traefik.http.services.dnsmasq-traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=5380`

and there arent any examples in the [docs](https://docs.traefik.io/reference/dynamic-configuration/file/)

---

the labels (this works perfectly)

```
- "traefik.http.routers.dnsmasq.rule=Host(`dnsmasq.docker.localdomain`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.dnsmasq.service=dnsmasq-traefik@docker"
- "traefik.http.services.dnsmasq-traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=5380"
```

the yaml (not working, gives me a `Gateway Timeout`)

```
http:
    routers:
        dnsmasq-preauth:
            entryPoints: [http]
            middlewares: [redirect-to-http]
            service: dnsmasq-preauth
            rule: Host(`dnsmasq.docker.localdomain`)

    services:
        dnsmasq-preauth:
            loadBalancer:
                servers:
                    - url: "http://dnsmasq.docker.localdomain:5380"
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I get this Gateway timeout issue I immediately look in two places:

1. The Traefik Config needs to be exposedByDefault - [docs here](https://docs.traefik.io/providers/docker/#exposedbydefault)

```
providers:
  docker:
    exposedByDefault: false
    # ...
```

If `exposedByDefault` is `false` then you need to do #2 in this list.

2. On your specific container you need to set the docker labels

```
- traefik.enable=true
```